# Typescript convert string union type to intersections of another type

Tags: typescript

I have the following union type:

```
type Foo = 'ol' | 'ul';
```

and I somehow want to convert that to this using a generic (as Foo might change to include others)

```
type Bar = OtherType<'ol'> & OtherType<'ul'>;
```

I'm not quite sure where to start...

EDIT: a more concrete example with React is:

```
type Elements = 'ol' | 'ul';

// ... somehow transform to:

type Props = JSX.IntrinsicElements['ol'] & JSX.IntrinsicElements['ul']
```

Comment: What is you have three or more property?

Comment: Then I'd want ```type Bar = OtherType<'ol'> & OtherType<'ul'>  & OtherType<'other'>```

Comment: Please share OtherType. Do you expect it to be some kind of object?

Comment: expected result is: `type Bar = 'ul' & 'ol';`??

Comment: This is not possible, it will evaluate to `never`

Comment: You might be looking for smth like this https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA8sAWEBOAVcEA8KoQB7AgDsATAZylOCQEtCBzAPigF4oADAEgG8UBfAWggAbCAFsiwNgCgpoSFABiAeyUtYCZGkgYA5EqE6oAHyg6ArgeOni1AG46GAbigB6F1CgAifYJHjCwJ5Wnha+YhJBJp42tmH+gVJAA

Comment: you can do something like `type OtherType<T extends Foo> = T;`  Your requirements aren't clear though

Comment: Updated with a more concrete example of what I want to get to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
import React from 'react'


// credits goes to https://stackoverflow.com/a/50375286
type UnionToIntersection<U> = (U extends any ? (k: U) => void : never) extends (
  k: infer I
) => void
  ? I
  : never;

type OtherType<T extends keyof JSX.IntrinsicElements> = UnionToIntersection<JSX.IntrinsicElements[T]>

type Result = OtherType<'ol' | 'ul'>;

declare var x: Result
declare var y: JSX.IntrinsicElements['ol'] & JSX.IntrinsicElements['ul']

x = y // ok

y = x // ok
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wChyB6CuNIgE2BgGc4BzCJFmCOACxhhgmALipMY6ANYQAbkiiYANhADuAOjS4KKCgFYADAGYA7LoBMADgBspGAE8wSOAFUAdsAiuAKhACSrmHkmJAwPVwAeZwA%20OABeOAAKZzgkAA9A1zoWFFc7OAB%20RMlhFwBKOJiZCGA6OBLXJDkocrSMrMTSODhiuGBXTHk4X1Jy2Mrquk6Coan6xvkAbnJ7RzgAeRheeS8HJHCvFPSkTJZJJDsITDgAKQBlAA01fxgoPqZgNABRRSQQY%20YYvE3GEfM8giEYGFwndHs9Xq53l8fn8AkwANpeAC6UWWu0QnAArop4PENlsoDtHOF8BBFPg4AAfAhE-BRJakOghRQoIhwGQ8uCpErIJhEmAcrk8pz8qBwOwlGFPALwxHfX7-dE0umYuAAMhuDyVLzeHzVKOYaPwLMx5FScTlcCocAgknIeXidqdLvIQA)

Union distribution will do the work for you

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution which will work in general, when `OtherType` may not distribute over unions: it takes advantage of contravariance of function parameter types in order to convert a union to an intersection.

```
type MakeIntersection<T> = (T extends infer U ? (x: OtherType<U>) => void : never) extends (x: infer V) => void ? V : never
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAECsFcGcBdQGYHsBOoCmAPAhgWwA4A26AULAJ77qgDysAFuigCqXoA8zAfKALygAldAGNUAE06gAZKAAKKJFRQUA0unIAaUHBQBLAHYBzLiTJtQAWWwBrdAEl9sJtBGxdSfZx78AFMwyYTvpi0KAGCEygAKqgAPygPpgAXLQMTKxU7FFcAJR8PABuSLpioCn66AVMeVhBIQnJYfoRaABqebyFxaXxrWWgFVUopiCpjCxs7ADkSIRTPDJ04xkcU5BzJhRUoMzocHyWNvaOzq7unjNzoAA+oGsbJEA)